# Checking if a user's entry is an integer using try catch statements

Tags: java, integer, try-catch, jtextfield

```
try {
        Character.isDigit(Integer.parseInt(txtWeight.getText()));

    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a number");
        pnlStart.setSelectedIndex(2);

    }
```

txtWeight is an JTextField that a user can enter their own value in. I need to check if what the user entered is an integer using a try catch so that the program doesn't crash when entered.

UPDATE:

```
boolean s = false;
    while (s == false) {
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(txtWeight.getText());
        s = false;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a number!");
            s =true;    
        }

    }
```

Comment: What's your question? Is something wrong with this code?

Comment: Well...The way I would do this for any signed, unsigned, integer, or double numerical values is to use this [Regular Expression](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) with the [**String.matches()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method: `if (s.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) { // Yup, it's numeric. }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your code isn't working?

The way I'd do it is to create a Boolean method and return true or false

```
boolean checkIfNumber(String s) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter a number!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Edit:**

What I'd do in this situation is, surround whatever code you are doing with an `if` statement calling the `boolean` method:

```
if (checkIfNumber(txtWeight.getText())) {
     //do your code here
} else {
     //do something else if necessary if the return is false
}
```

Comment: My code picks up that it is incorrect data, displays the message in the catch statement but runs the code despite the return statements. I was thinking to use a while loop but I don't know how to work that into this problem.

Comment: Ah ok. I'd have to see more of your code and I can update my answer.

Comment: I just added what changed to try fix it

Comment: @RobertNorth answer updated